# I dont understand why this code with switch statement dont gives a compilation error or throw an runtime exception

Tags: java, switch-statement

```java
int param1 = 1;
        switch (param1){
            case 0:
                int block2 = 10; // if this line is commented gives a compilation error
                System.out.println(block2);
                break;
            case 1:
                block2 = 5; // if this line is commented below line gives a compilation error
                System.out.println(block2);
                break;
            default:
//                System.out.println(block2); // comilation error
        }
```

I try debug and dont makes sence because I dont see the declaration of the variable. this code run in a main

Comment: "*... I dont see the declaration of the variable." - Which variable?

Comment: Please be more precise. What exactly do you mean with "I dont see the declaration of the variable"? Are you refering to `int block2`? That is clearly declared in case 0, and since java cases fall through and don't have their own scope it is therefor also available in other cases.

Comment: does this answer your question htps://stackoverflow.com/questions/47543667/jpql-query-hibernate-with-clause-not-allowed-on-fetched-associations

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I dint know that, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a quirk of `switch` expressions. The Java compiler allows you to declare the variable, and to reference it *if* it has been initialized. That's why you need to assign it, so why your case `2` gives a compilation error: It sees the declaration from case `0`, but there's no initialization, so you can't reference it.

However, this code is confusing, and you shouldn't write it like this. Use a different variable for each `case`. An IDE like IntelliJ will generate a warning if you do it this way:

> Local variable 'block2' declared in one 'switch' branch and used in another